# Data augmentation layer doesn't change the input picture

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to apply data argumentation to increase the amount of training data.

The code is shown below. The augmentation layer consists of `RandomFlip` and `RandomRotation`.

```
def data_augmenter():
    '''
    Create a Sequential model composed of 2 layers
    Returns:
        tf.keras.Sequential
    '''
    ### START CODE HERE
    data_augmentation = tf.keras.Sequential()
    data_augmentation.add((RandomFlip('horizontal')))
    data_augmentation.add(RandomRotation(0.2))
    ### END CODE HERE
    
    return data_augmentation

data_augmentation = data_augmenter()

for image, _ in train_dataset.take(1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    first_image = image[0]
    plt.imshow(first_image / 255)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
    for i in range(9):
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
        augmented_image = data_augmentation(tf.cast(tf.expand_dims(first_image, 0), tf.float32))
        plt.imshow(augmented_image[0] / 255)
        plt.axis('off')
```

[Output Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlnIq.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `training=True` to the model call? Those random preprocessing layers only do their random thing when in training mode, else they work in a deterministic fashion for inference.

Comment: I am not using a pre-trained model. In other word, I am just feeding a image though a function that do random flip and rotation

Comment: Check the documentation (always), these layers do nothing during inference time, so you need to specify training=True for them to do anything.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with my apple silicon Macbook Pro. To make it work, I set the parameter `training=True` when I passed the augmentation layer.

See the image attached as an example.

[image: 1]